# RDDs auxiliares dentro de funcion map

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

Soy Nuevo en Apache Spark. Tengo una consulta con respecto a los RDD y las transformaciones. Tengo un PairRDD con datos cargados ya. Y ahora lo que necesito, es: a través de una transformacion (maptoPair), de forma que pueda obtener en otro pairRDD, la tupla que cumpla cierta condicion y además agregar info adicional a la tupla (por eso un map y no un filter).
Dicha condicion se basa en para cada tupl (K,V) obtener de otro rdd diferente (tambien clave-valor), todas las tuplas que contengan a K, y todas las tuplas que contengan a V, y luego obtener la intersección. El código que he planteado hasta ahora es el siguiente.

```
JavaPairRDD<Long,Long> originalRDD = .... //se carga de un dataset
JavaPairRDD<Long,Long> otro = ......; //de aca saco las tuplas
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Long, Long>, Long> result = otro
                .mapToPair(tupla-> {
                    JavaRDD<Long> aux1;
                    JavaRDD<Long> aux2;
                    aux1 = originalRDD.filter(T -> T._1.equals(tupla._1)).values().flatMap(f -> f);
                    aux2 = originalRDD.filter(T -> T._2.equals(tupla._2)).values().flatMap(f -> f);
                    JavaPairRDD<Long,Long> auxfinal = aux1.intersect(aux2);
                    //aca vendria el codigo que resta que agrega la infoadicional a la tupla (no es relevante al caso este codigo)
                    //devolver la info al RESULT
                });
```

Si lo programo de esta forma, los ejecutores que tomen esta función lambda informan al Driver que hay que crear nuevas Tasks referentes a los intersect y a los filter?? o el mismo ejecutor se encargaría de hacer TODO? (perdiendo total grado de paralelismo a nivel Job) Puesto que en ninguna bibliografía he encontrado un caso como este para saber qué ocurre cuando hay anidamiento de transformaciones (nesting). Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

No puedes añadir una transformación dentro de otra transformación, ya que los `RDD` se crean en el driver y las transformaciones se hacen en los ejecutores.

En tu caso, el filtrado que haces en las variables `aux1` y `aux2` lo puedes hacer fuera y usarlo como variables tipo lista (no `rdds`), aunque esta aproximación es bastante nefasta y no hace uso de las características de paralelización de spark. Creo que sería más adecuado añadir columnas y usar joins, quizás empleando variables `RDD` auxiliares, pero desde luego no puedes usar transformaciones dentro de una transformación